# Strange URL Rewrite Issues in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Im having a very bizarre problem with a magento store that I work on. I have been doing the SEO and have about 100 404 errors for product urls that SHOULD be valid.

I can see the products and the urls in the product catalog via the admin - everything is correct there. If I try to load the product by its url key using the product model I get the correct product back (a configurable product with id 12457 - this is important for later).

But if I try to load the page by the url path - it wont load - instead I get a 404 error - even with developer mode - I get no insight into the issue as there isnt really ANYTHING to follow in the `system.log` or in the Varien profiler / debugger except the normal `noRouteAction` stuff that comes up.

So I started investigating the `core_url_rewrites` table to see if I could identify multiple (duplicate) urls. Sure enough - I did. The `core_url_rewrite` table had over 30000 rows with 2.5x the # of products for the product group so I deleted the rows in the table and reindexed.

This gave me the proper count of products - and I can see that there is a duplicate url issue of some sort:

```
+----------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| url_rewrite_id | store_id | id_path            | request_path                                                                                    | target_path                                 | is_system | options | description | category_id | product_id |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|         200513 |        1 | product/12279      | torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc-cigars.html                                                     | catalog/product/view/id/12279               |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        NULL |      12279 |
|         200514 |        1 | product/12280      | torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc-single-cigar.html                                               | catalog/product/view/id/12280               |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        NULL |      12280 |
|         200759 |        1 | product/12408      | torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc.html                                                            | catalog/product/view/id/12408               |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        NULL |      12408 |
|         200760 |        1 | product/12408/8    | all-brands/torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc.html                                                 | catalog/product/view/id/12408/category/8    |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |           8 |      12408 |
|         200761 |        1 | product/12408/3535 | all-brands/torano-cigars/torano-exodus-1959-50-years/torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc.html       | catalog/product/view/id/12408/category/3535 |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        3535 |      12408 |
|         200762 |        1 | product/12408/3708 | all-brands/torano-cigars/torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc.html                                   | catalog/product/view/id/12408/category/3708 |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        3708 |      12408 |
|         200901 |        1 | product/12457      | torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc-12457.html                                                      | catalog/product/view/id/12457               |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        NULL |      12457 |
|         200902 |        1 | product/12457/3535 | all-brands/torano-cigars/torano-exodus-1959-50-years/torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc-12457.html | catalog/product/view/id/12457/category/3535 |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        3535 |      12457 |
|         200903 |        1 | product/12457/3708 | all-brands/torano-cigars/torano-exodus-1959-50-years-bfc-12457.html                             | catalog/product/view/id/12457/category/3708 |         1 | NULL    | NULL        |        3708 |      12457 |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

It appears that product #12408 is taking the URL that belongs to 12457 - so logically I went to find product # 12408 to correct the issue - however - after searching the admin  - as well as just querying the database there ISN'T an `entity_id` 12408 in `catalog_product_flat_x` that I can find.

This is obviously a problem - and at this point I dont know where to go looking for 12408 to either correct it or remove it so it stops breaking 12457's url.

Can anyone out there tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: i think your product 12408 is disabled, that's why this is not in flat table. but you can find it in admin > catalog > products grid. If it is not there then you can fix this by deleting rows in rewrite table and modify you product url to correct one.

Comment: @Gulshan - its not in the admin at all - cant find it anywhere. Thats why I truncated core_url_rewrite and rebuilt it. The problem is that after I rebuilt 12408 showed up again even though it didnt show up in the admin - its like a "ghost" but I have no idea where its references are.

Comment: An Update : I did find that 12408 is referenced by a category - but even after checking the EAV I cannot find the product. It doesnt exist in the system. I suspect it did and was deleted, BUT some references clearly remain - I need to find out where these references are so that I can delete them and rebuild the core_url_rewrite table properly.